# Weird characters in stdout buffer. Prepended by zsh shell

Tags: c, shell, c++11, zsh, pty

What I am trying to do is to create and run a pseudo-terminal with it's output redirected to a pipe. The issue is that zsh (or any shell for that matter) outputs with a bunch of characters that I believe are meant to set some console settings, but reading them directly from the file descriptors means I cannot get rid them.

The following is a code snippet from my program:

```
                rc = read(fdm, input, sizeof(input));
                if (rc > 0)
                {
                    // Send data on standard output (toTG)
                    //parent.logNS(input);
                    write(1, input, rc);
                    write(toTG, input, rc);
                }
```

In the above code, I am redirecting the output to both stdout as well as a pipe.
image 1: expected output (also the console processed one)
[image: expected output]

image 2: What I see after writing the raw buffer to the pipe. I need to eliminate the extra characters here so that it looks like the output in the first image :
[image: output with extra characters]

here,

> [1m [7m% [27m [1m [0m
> [0m [27m [24m [J ...  [K [?2004h-Air
> build %  [K [?2004h

seem to be the extra characters.

Possible solutions :

- Since this is a console thing, I believe it would more sense to start the console with maybe some flags or settings to disable this.
- I could send the raw buffer to stdout and pipe it from there to my desired location using a string stream or a file. Though this will be done within the program itself, I think it will be a bit messy.
- Is there any other way to process the raw buffer preferably within the program code itself?

Comment: Parse the control codes, and filter them out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: These are control codes telling the terminal to change colour for example. You can try filtering them out using the ANSI escape code rules (they all follow a few patterns, you don't need to know each code individually). You could also try setting the environment variable `TERM=dumb` (variable name = TERM, value = dumb) or `TERM=unknown`, and then the program might not output them because it thinks your terminal doesn't understand colours and stuff.

Comment: @user253751 I tried this and it definitely cleared some characters out but there still some characters like ->  [?2004h@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@"

Comment: @nalostta ^@ is a null character, you are doing something wrong handling the end of the read data. I notice that you don't tell parent.logNS how many bytes you read

Comment: @user253751 actually parent.logNS is commented out, so it shouldn't matter. I am directly sending the raw stream, maybe I should only copy string length number of bytes

Comment: @nalostta whoever is receiving the stream might have a bug, too

Comment: You basically copy the input verbatim to the output, byte by byte. Isn't this what you want to achieve? If you want to implement a filter feature, you need to analyze your `input` buffer to see, which bytes you are going to throw away. However, you basically process a set of binary data. If you want to remove certain pattern (sequences) of bytes, you have to pay attention that such a sequence may start in your current input buffer and end in the following input buffer.